# Change output encoding for `gradle run` (cp866)

Tags: gradle, encoding, console

How to change the output encoding for `gradle run`? (cyrillic text)

Default system encoding - windows-1251
Default console encoding - cp866

If I run using gradle, then the output will be the wrong encoding.
[image]

Here is an example of the correct encoding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

solution:

set **env var**

`GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=cp866"`
and

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=windows-1251' //(Default encoding)
```

Comment: You can also set that in the gradle.properties file with `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=cp866`

Comment: This does not work (does not solve my problem) and should not work.

Comment: Just to nuance this a little: setting the encoding in gradle.properties controls the encoding used for compiling your source code. But it's true that it does not have an effect when running it through the Application plugin. If you like to have a solution that does not involve setting environment variables (as that is not project specific), you can set `application { applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Dfile.encoding=cp866'] }` in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Indeed, this solves my problem, but adds another. Now the charset of the daemon and the application is cp866, the latter can be harmful for last.